# Where can I find and download netdb.h?

Tags: c

I tried to compile a `.c` file but  it returns the error:

```
yay.c:6:19: fatal error: netdb.h: No such file or directory
 #include <netdb.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

I did some research and apparently `.h` is a header file for C...

I am new to C so I don't know what to do.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: `netdb.h` appears to come with libc (or at least glibc), which must be available on your system (including header files, some distro split those out and leave them out by default) and your compiler (pre-processor really) must know where to find it's header files (either be in default headers search path or added through `-I` or similar flag.

Comment: [`netdb.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netdb.h.html) is part of POSIX.1 standard (also known as IEEE Std 1003.1).  Are you using Windows, perhaps?  If so, you must use the proprietary Microsoft interfaces instead, I'm afraid.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/cpp/missinghdr.html

Comment: (@OndrejK.: Actually, [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) features are an integral part of the C libraries, and are never "split out".  You can remove the headers if you want, but the features would still exist in the standard C library.  Remember, when compiling POSIX.1 C code, you link against the standard C library with POSIX.1 features -- that is the purpose of POSIX.1 system interfaces! --, and not against some separate POSIX.1 library. Thus, omitting or separating the POSIX.1 headers from standard C headers would be rather odd.)

Comment: In general, when installing libraries on Linux, Macs, or BSDs, they often are split into *binary run-time* and *development* versions, like @OndrejK. alluded to.  This applies to even the standard C library: you usually have the normal run-time package that is always installed; but to write your own code, you also need to install the *development* version of the package.  Sometimes, the development version includes only the header files, but often there is additional documentation and information too.  Usually, these development packages are named with a `-dev` or `-devel` suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `locate netdb.h` under [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) to find out (the file [path](/questions/tagged/path)).

Under [openbsd](/questions/tagged/openbsd) it is in located at [`/usr/include/netdb.h`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/include/netdb.h?rev=HEAD) (installed with the [`compXX`](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#FilesNeeded) file set, and not being packaged as `glibc`)

[c](/questions/tagged/c) headers are usually placed in `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include` directories depending on if they are system or local (third-party, custom), respectively.

Comment: Why are you linking random words to SO tag definitions? Also, if the file were already under `/usr/include`, OP wouldn't get that error.

Comment: I only link if the 'words' **exist** as tags (for reference). Yes, that is why it is proper to do `locate` first.

Comment: Reference of what? Your links go simply to a tag search, showing all questions that have the same tag. I don't think that's helpful.

Comment: Yes, but there is the tag description section, being visible first, which can be very helpful to familiarize, and also explore more on specific terms i think, for all users.